# AWK count number of times a term appear with respect to other columns

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, awk, sed

Given a CSV file:

```
id, fruit, binary
1, apple, 1
2, orange, 0
3, pear, 1
4, apple, 0
5, peach, 0
6, apple, 1
```

How can i calculate for each unique values in fruit,

> the number of times the binary value =1 / number of occurences of that
>   fruit appearing in the fruit column
>   ?

Another way to do it is to sum the value of the binary column for for each unique fruit.

For example:

For the fruit apple, it appeared with binary = 1 two times and had a frequency of 3. Hence i will get 2/3.

How can i write this in an efficient AWK code?

I know that i can do this to get unique values from the second column:

```
cut -d , -f2 file.csv | sort | uniq |
```

or

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ } END { for (b in a) { print b } }' file.csv
```

So my non-working code looks like this:

```
 cat file.csv | awk '{ a[$2]++ } END { for (b in a) if ($3==1) {sum+=$3} END {print $0 sum}'
```

and

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ } END { for (b in a) { sum +=1 } }' file.csv
```

need help in correcting my syntax and merging the 2 awk codes

Comment: I think the answer in this question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450085/list-only-duplicate-lines-based-on-one-column-from-a-semi-colon-delimited-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you?

```
 $ cat file.csv
    1, apple, 1
    2, orange, 0
    3, pear, 1
    4, apple, 0
    5, peach, 0
    6, apple, 1

$ cat file.csv|awk -F',' '{ $3 == 1 && fruit[$2]++; tfruit[$2]++ } END { for ( fr in tfruit) { print fr, fruit[fr], tfruit[fr] } }'
 pear 1 1
 apple 2 3
 orange  1
 peach  1
```

Comment: Can you print zero instead of blanks for the first column and have an extra column to get the final value? Also, what does  tfruit[$2]++ mean?

Comment: Hope you got the explanation from other answer by A.M.D

Comment: Could you help me with my last comment above?

Comment: should be simple. just after printing a[i],b[i] add a[i]/b[i] to print 4th column

Comment: awk -F',' '{ fr[$2]+=$3; tf[$2]++ } END { for ( f in tf) { print f, fr[f], tf[f], fr[f]/tf[f] } }' file

Comment: when i implement AMD's code, i get decimals for the second column but yours was fine. any idea why?

Comment: sorry, second column is count, isn't it? should be a decimal. Is your input file changed?

Comment: second column is sum of binary values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81321/discussion-between-venkatc-and-jenn).

Answer (score 0):

Almost same as the other answer, but printing `0` instead of blank.

```
AMD$ awk -F, 'NR>1{a[$2]+=$3;b[$2]++} END{for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i]}' File
pear 1 1
apple 2 3
orange 0 1
peach 0 1
```

Taking `,` as field seperator. For all lines except the first, update array `a`. i.e `$2(fruit name)` is taken as index and adding up the number of times `binary` is `1` for this fruit. Also increase `b[$2]` by one, this will be the number of times the `fruit` is seen. At the end, print the `fruit`, `binary count` and `num of times fruit seen`. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Im pretty new to awk so can i clarify: when there is an END in the code, does this mean that the code will run from right (after the END) then go to the left ( `{a[$2]+=$3;b[$2]++}`), Similar to writing a for loop? (i.e. for i in array: do this) Also, is `a` and `b` two separate arrays that you defined?

Comment: Yes, a and b are seperate arrays... END { } will be executed at the end of processing all the lines...Similarly BEGIN { } will be executed before beginning processing the first line... You can google on this...

Comment: Is it possible to add a new column ($4) that is equal to $2/$3 within the code?

Comment: actually getting decimal values for the second column, could something be missing?